# Factorial calculation giving wrong answer with float or decimal number

Tags: kotlin, gamma-function

this code is working fine to calculate factorial,but giving wrong answer with float or decimal number

```
    fun factorial(number: BigDecimal): BigDecimal {
        if (number >= BigDecimal(3000)) {
            is_infinity = true
            return BigDecimal.ZERO
        }
        return if (number < BigDecimal.ZERO) {
            domain_error = true
            BigDecimal.ZERO
        } else {
            val decimalPartOfNumber = number.toDouble() - number.toInt()
            if (decimalPartOfNumber == 0.0) {
                var factorial = BigInteger("1")
                for (i in 1..number.toInt()) {
                    factorial *= i.toBigInteger()
                }
                factorial.toBigDecimal()
            } else gammaLanczos(number + BigDecimal.ONE)
        }
    }

    private fun gammaLanczos(x: BigDecimal): BigDecimal {
        // https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Gamma_function
        var xx = x
        val p = doubleArrayOf(
            0.9999999999998099,
            676.5203681218851,
            -1259.1392167224028,
            771.3234287776531,
            -176.6150291621406,
            12.507343278686905,
            -0.13857109526572012,
            9.984369578019572E-6,
            1.5056327351493116e-7
        )
        val g = BigDecimal(7)
        if (xx < BigDecimal(0.5)) return (Math.PI / (sin(Math.PI * xx.toDouble()) * gammaLanczos(BigDecimal(1.0 - xx.toDouble())).toDouble())).toBigDecimal()
        xx--
        var a = p[0]
        val t = xx + g + BigDecimal(0.5)
        for (i in 1 until p.size) a += p[i] / (xx.toDouble() + i)
        return (sqrt(2.0 * Math.PI) * t.toDouble().pow(xx.toInt() + 0.5) * exp(-t.toDouble()) * a).toBigDecimal()
    }
```

For the code below, the test is failing after running nine the code

```
@Test
    fun sqrt() {

        val result =  NumberFormatter.factorial(BigDecimal(3.03))
        assertEquals(6.23120891259, result.toFloat())
    }
```

got this expected:<6.23120891259> but was:<5.8062997>

Could anyone help with this. Thanks

Comment: This is due to precision loss from converting BigDecimal to double for mathematical operations, which can introduce inaccuracies in calculations

Comment: Please could you help with right code

Comment: See http://obermuhlner.ch/wordpress/2018/04/03/implementing-non-integer-factorial-and-gamma-function-for-bigdecimal/

Comment: @Muraino the difference between 6.23 and 5.80 cannot be due to precision loss. Even `float` has at least 6 or 7 significant figures. This difference is not even close to 2 significant figure2.

Comment: The `BigDecimal` class was never really designed for mathematical/scientific calculations - that's what the `double` type is for. Also, you're not getting any advantage from using `BigDecimal` if you keep converting to/from `double` or `float`.

Comment: Your error is at `t.toDouble().pow(xx.toInt() + 0.5)`. Leave out the `toInt()`. Then you'll get the correct answer.

Comment: @k314159 we are saying the same thing in different context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code has precision loss due to the conversion between BigDecimal and double. you can update the gammaLanczos to

```
fun gammaLanczos(x: BigDecimal): BigDecimal {
// Lanczos approximation parameters
   val p = arrayOf(
       676.5203681218851,
      -1259.1392167224028,
      771.3234287776531,
      -176.6150291621406,
      12.507343278686905,
      -0.13857109526572012,
      9.984369578019572e-6,
      1.5056327351493116e-7
  )
  val g = 7.0
  var z = x.toDouble() - 1.0

  var a = 0.99999999999980993
  for (i in p.indices) {
      a += p[i] / (z + i + 1)
  }

  val t = z + g + 0.5
  val sqrtTwoPi = sqrt(2.0 * PI)
  val firstPart = sqrtTwoPi * t.pow(z + 0.5) * exp(-t)
  val result = firstPart * a

  return BigDecimal(result, MathContext.DECIMAL64)
}

fun BigDecimal.pow(exponent: Double): BigDecimal {
   return this.toDouble().pow(exponent).toBigDecimal(MathContext.DECIMAL64)
}
```

Comment: Your code gives the right answer, but the OP's incorrect result was not caused by precision loss. See my comment under the question for the actual cause of error.

Comment: we are saying same thing in different context.... since BigDecimal was not designed for scientific calculation, it causes precision loss from conversion

Comment: No, the difference in the result is because the OP is doing `xx.toInt()` where they should just have `xx` (see my comment to the OP). If they left out the `toInt()` the result would be the same as yours, and the same as if they used `double` throughout. As I said earlier, the difference between 6.2 and 5.8 is far too big to be explained by loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be to use the [Apache commons math](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) library. The version three docs for `Gamma` are [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/org/apache/commons/math3/special/Gamma.html).

Sample code to calculate `3.03!`

```kotlin
Gamma.gamma(1 + 3.03)
    .also { check(it == 6.231208912587357 ) }
```

Version four has been in the works for a while. If you are interested, the current Java source is [here](https://github.com/apache/commons-numbers/blob/master/commons-numbers-gamma/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/numbers/gamma/BoostGamma.java).